# Robot framework Ride installation issue on Ubuntu OS

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I have done all installation related to robot framework but when I install robot framework-ride that time through some error on the command line  "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)".

1.`sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8`

> python-wxgtk2.8 is already the newest version (2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2).
>   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

2.`pip install robotframework`

> Requirement already satisfied: robotframework in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (3.1.1)

3. `sudo pip install robotframework-ride`

> Collecting Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)

Expected: robot framework should be installed successfully on my ubuntu os.

Actual result : 'sudo pip install robotframework-ride'

Collecting Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)

Comment: [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) is a module for MS Windows. You cannot have it on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
    libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev
```

then :

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev \
    libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev \
    libsdl1.2-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev \
    libnotify-dev freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libsm-dev \
    libwebkitgtk-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
```

> This took a long time, ~30min

after :

`pip install -U -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robotframework/RIDE/master/requirements.txt`

Finally :

```
git clone git@github.com:robotframework/RIDE.git
cd RIDE
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Run Ride :

```
ride.py &
```

> Reference : https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/1811

Answer (score 0):

Ir you want, you can install newest development version, with:

```
sudo pip  install -U https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/archive/master.zip
```